# Illustrator: Asset exports creates artifacts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, asset-management

I have an illustrator document with lots of assets which will be transported to InDesign. It's a library of drawings that initially come from CAD.

Each one is grouped and added to the asset export panel. When exported (SVG) many (most) images have some "artifacts" in them. These can be extra points, extra lines, extra writing far away from the main image. These later appear on the asset export panel (usually after they have been exported already).

It's very annoying because I'm setting it up to get ID to update automatically and the problem means I have to edit each frame individually.

I am *absolutely certain* these extra things are not in the original selection or the original group. If it's of any relevance many assets are on more than one layer.

How does this happen? Does this happen to anyone else? Is export asset just buggy?

Should I just create many artbords and export those?

Thanks for any help, it's driving me nuts.

Comment: How do you propose we do anything about this issue? Right now your question contains nothing more than "i went to work with my car, i work at X, now my driver seat door does not open. Im sure its not broken". Can you atleast include any info that we could start figuring out the problem. Have you killed all clipping masks?

Comment: I was hoping it was a known issue or that it had happened to someone. After a lot of digging around I think it's something to do with:

1) Paths are too complex. A lot of simplifying has helped a bit with the issue.

2) Asset export doesn't handle layers very well and will move them around when exporting.

I still haven't solved it completely though. Happy to give additional info, but there's not much. They are complex paths, with no gradients, almost no fills. Clipping masks don't seem to be the problem (as long as they are all in the same asset, of course)

Comment: impossible to say. I havent heard if such issues. Note i personally dont use the asset export since i have better tools for that. Also please use  @ and name to ping user otherwise they might not see your comment

Comment: Hidden objects maybe.. Object > Unhide All ----- Or locked... Object > Unlock All -- Just guessing.

Comment: What happens if you save SVG without asset export? What do you see in outline mode? Can you find those extra writings for example?

Comment: One thing is *certain* if there are extra elements upon export those elements **are** in the file. You merely may not be able to *see* them.